Unable to add EF Core Migration since update to .net 8
Since upgrading to EFCore 8, we're seeing the following stack trace when trying to add any migration.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Extensions.KnownTypes' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Extensions.KnownTypes' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Extensions.KnownTypes' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Extensions.KnownTypes' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Extensions.KnownTypes' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Extensions.KnownTypes' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Roslyn.Utilities.IObjectWritable' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Checksum' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' due to value type mismatch.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Checksum' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' due to value type mismatch.
Could not load type 'ItemCompletedDisposer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.<>c.<WithAssemblies>b__16_0(Assembly a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Composition.TypedParts.TypedPartExportDescriptorProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 types, AttributedModelProvider attributeContext)
   at System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.CreateContainer()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.Create(IEnumerable`1 assemblies)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.get_DefaultHost()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AdhocWorkspace..ctor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper..ctor(ITypeMappingSource typeMappingSource)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithOneArg(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

Downing back to .net 6 & EF Core 6 works perfectly as expected. Can't see any breaking changes that would cause this.
My project is currently using at version 8.0.2.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Anyone experiencing similar?

Using PMC or PowerShell ?

Looks like you have to update Microsoft.CodeAnalysis packages.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv they were at the latest version, I've removed them completely and this has actually solved my issue.

@DarkkL it was PMC, apologies for not including this

You can also show the command itself
